# How to call function recursively

Tags: angularjs, recursion

I'm trying to call my mapper function recursively but getting the error not defined: 'ReferenceError: mapper is not defined at Object.mapper'

Could use some guidance on how to call the function recursively in this particular situation.

```
angular.module('dvb.transferObjects').value('MappedTransferObject', function(obj1) {
    'use strict';

    return { 
        mapper: function(obj2) {
            for (var p in obj1) {
                if (typeof obj1[p] === 'object') {
                    mapper(obj1[p], obj2[p]);
                } else {
                    if(obj2.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                        obj1[p] = obj2[p];
                    }
                }
            }
            return obj1;
        }
    };
});
```

I'm injecting this value in my controller as MTO and using it as follows:

```
var mto = new MTO(appState.getTemplateObject());
var mappedObject = mto.mapper($scope.dvModel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a name to your anonymous function you can call it inside itself like so:

```
angular.module('dvb.transferObjects').value('MappedTransferObject', function (obj1) {
    'use strict';


    return {
        mapper: function mapper(obj2) {
            for (var p in obj1) {
                if (typeof obj1[p] === 'object') {
                    mapper(obj1[p], obj2[p]);
                } else {
                    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                        obj1[p] = obj2[p];
                    }
                }
            }
            return obj1;
        }
    };
});
```

The reason you can not use `mapper` in your example is due to the `mapper` being scoped to the object itself. This means the only way to access the function would be to call it through the object, which you can't do without saving off a reference to the object before returning it:

```
angular.module('dvb.transferObjects').value('MappedTransferObject', function (obj1) {
    'use strict';

    var mapper = {
        mapper: function (obj2) {
            for (var p in obj1) {
                if (typeof obj1[p] === 'object') {
                    mapper.mapper(obj1[p], obj2[p]);
                } else {
                    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                        obj1[p] = obj2[p];
                    }
                }
            }
            return obj1;
        }
    };

    return mapper;
});
```