# Calling function recursively in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to call a function recursively (for sorting purposes) but getting an error. I tried to find a solution and found [How to call function recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743150/how-to-call-function-recursively);
I changed my code accordingly, so now it looks like this:

```
$scope.orderCustom = function() {

    qS.quickSort($scope.mydata, 0, mydata.length-1);
};

var qS = {
    quickSort: function quickSort(data, min, max) {

        if (min < max) {
            var p = qSP.quickSortPartition(data, min, max);
            var newMax = p-1;
            var newMin = p+1;

            qS.quicksort(data, min, newMax);
            qS.quicksort(data, newMin, max);
        }
    }
};

var qSP = {
    quickSortPartition: function quickSortPartition(data, min, max) {

        var pivot = data[max].id;
        var i = min;
        for (var j = min; j <= max; j++) {
            if (data[j].id <= pivot) {
                var pom = data[j];
                data[j] = data[i];
                data[i] = pom;
                i = i+1;
            }
        }  
        var pom = data[i];
        data[i] = data[max];
        data[max] = pom;    

        return i;
    }
};
```

I'm getting an error "Error: qS.quicksort is not a function". Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
I am still not able to leave a comment on stackoverflow, so I had to open a new question for this. Any help would be appriciated. Thanx :)

Comment: Just call `quickSort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to get rid of the extra wrapping and just use the functions:

```
$scope.orderCustom = function() {

    quickSort($scope.mydata, 0, mydata.length-1);
};

function quickSort(data, min, max) {

        if (min < max) {
            var p = quickSortPartition(data, min, max);
            var newMax = p-1;
            var newMin = p+1;

            quickSort(data, min, newMax);
            quickSort(data, newMin, max);
        }
}

function quickSortPartition(data, min, max) {

        var pivot = data[max].id;
        var i = min;
        for (var j = min; j <= max; j++) {
            if (data[j].id <= pivot) {
                var pom = data[j];
                data[j] = data[i];
                data[i] = pom;
                i = i+1;
            }
        }  
        var pom = data[i];
        data[i] = data[max];
        data[max] = pom;    

        return i;
}
```

Note that you also have to correct the spelling of the recursive call `quickSort` as you had used all lower case `quicksort`.

I assume this is just a programming exercise as you would be better for real code to use the built-in `sort()` function or for angular you might prefer the `orderBy` filter.

For example, this does the same as you look to be trying to do:

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.id < b.id)
    return -1;
  if (a.id > b.id)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

$scope.mydata.sort(compare);
```

Comment: Aaaah, what a stupid mistake. Sure, the thing was in a typo, quicksort instead of quickSort. Nice catch. Ofcourse it works now, without wrapping (as I initially wrote it). Thank you so much, it would bug me for who knows how long :)

Comment: Btw, I can't use orderBy here, that is why I am writing sort by myself (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572744/angularjs-filter-orderby-ordering-one-variable-by-another)

Comment: @ljerka, you should be able to just call sort with a comparison function, see the edit to my post.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am quite new in those stuff... But if I write $scope.mydata.sort(compare), how does compare(a, b) "know" what are my a & b? Btw, what I am trying to sort is a collection that has an id from another collection, and I would like to sort it by a name property from that other collection. So it is not so simple as to compare 2 id-s

Comment: `a` and `b` are the values the sort function wants to compare, so elements of the array being sorted. If I understand you, you actually want to compare `othercollection[a.id].someattribute < othercollection[b.id].someattribute` ? It makes the compare function longer but not much harder.

Comment: No, I have firstColl[i].idSecondColl, but instead want to compare secondColl[someIndex].name where secondColl[someIndex].id == firstColl[i].idSecondColl, and secondColl[someIndex].name where secondColl[someIndex].id == firstColl[j].idSecondColl (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572744/angularjs-filter-orderby-ordering-one-variable-by-another for more details, if I didn't explain it good)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mention `qS`.

Just `quicksort` instead of `qS.quicksort`.